# Участие в гонке http запросов

Tags: http, post, okhttp

Есть сервер, который ровно в 0:00:00.000 начинает следующее соревнование: тот, чей post запрос придет первым, получит виртуальный приз, а все остальные не получат ничего. При каждом ответе север возвращает параметр serverTime, в котором содержится серверное время с точностью до миллисекунды. Сервер находится где-то в Калифорнии, я арендовал сервер там же и пытаюсь победить в этом соревновании. Я использую Java и библиотеку OkHttp в режиме http2, отправляю "пристрелочный" post запрос секунд за 10 до нужного времени (который занимает около 1 секунды), далее синхронизирую время по ntp и отправляю запрос заранее так, чтобы он приходил на сервер как можно ближе к нужному времени. По результатам экспериментов я отправляю запрос за 22 мс до нужного времени, сам запрос занимает от 29 до 40 мс и на сервер приходит всегда по разному. Когда в 999 мс предыдущего часа, когда в 001 мс, когда в 004, а когда и в 016. 
Это соревнование я проигрываю с завидной регулярностью, а что бы вы сделали на моем месте, чтобы не допускать подобных поражений?)
Технические характеристики: скорость интернета на сервере, согласно speedtest'у: 700/400 мбит, пинг до нужного айпишника: 1.4 мс
Возможны любые решения: арендовать другой сервер, сменить язык программирования и библиотеку и т.д.

Comment: `а что бы вы сделали на моем месте` - не участвовал бы в этой глупости :)

Comment: Вы ведь не создаете `OkHttpClient` заново после предварительного запроса?

Comment: @Zergatul, нет, конечно, иначе в чем смысл этого запроса?)